# iPhone time comparison

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to figure out how to create an 'if' statement that uses a time value as a condition.  For example:

```
if (time <= 10:00) {
    score = 3;
} else if (time <= 20:00) {
    score = 5;
} else {
            score = 9;
}
```

I know that a string of "5:23" cannot be compared this way but I don't think I can just turn a string value like that directly into an integer.  Any thoughts?

Comment: This makes me wonder if 00:00 < 24:00.  You probably would like to check `NSDateFormatter` & `-[NSDate dateFromString:]` out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSString *realTimeString = @"10:00";
NSString *someTimeString = [realTimeString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":"
                                           withString:@"."];
float time = [someTimeString floatValue];

if (time <= 10.00) {
    score = 3;
} else if (time <= 20.00) {
    score = 5;
} else {
    score = 9;
}
```